How to draw up and down arrow in tikzcd
I want to draw the following diagram using tikzcd.

I tried:
\begin{tikzcd}
    P_3 \arrow[r,"D_3"] \arrow[d,"a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
        a\\b\\c\\d
    \end{pmatrix}"] & P_2 \arrow[d,"a+bx+cx^2\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
        a\\b\\c
    \end{pmatrix}"]\\
    \mathbb R^4 \arrow[r, "A"] & \mathbb R^3
\end{tikzcd}

Now, the issue is, that I need an up and down arrow instead of a down. And my text aren't rendered in a nice way. The below image is my output.

How to fix this problem. Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Thank you for your suggestion. I will remember that while posting Question this site, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

You can use the leftrightarrow option to get an arrow with heads on both sides:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
    P_3 \arrow[r,"D_3"]  & P_2 \arrow[d,leftrightarrow,"a+bx+cx^2\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
            a\\b\\c
        \end{pmatrix}"]\\
    \mathbb R^4 \arrow[u,leftrightarrow,"a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
            a\\b\\c\\d
        \end{pmatrix}\quad"] \arrow[r, "A"] & \mathbb R^3
\end{tikzcd}


\end{document}



You want to specify <-> for the arrows.
In order to change the side of a label, use "<label>"' (with a single quote after the closing double quote).
Also psmallmatrix from mathtools is a better choice than pmatrix, not only because the size is reduced. In labels to arrows, tikz-cd imposes \scriptstyle, so you'd get small letters anyway, but with large vertical space between them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}% generic
\newcommand{\RR}{\numberset{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
  P_3
  \arrow[r,<->,"D_3"]
  \arrow[d,<->,"a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\mapsto\begin{psmallmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{psmallmatrix}"']
  &
  P_2
  \arrow[d,<->,"a+bx+cx^2\mapsto\begin{psmallmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{psmallmatrix}"]
  \\
  \RR^4 \arrow[r,<->, "A"] & \RR^3
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}

I also added \RR for the real numbers: shorter and possibly more semantic.

If you want to reproduce the picture, with some improvement:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}% generic
\newcommand{\RR}{\numberset{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
  P_3
  \arrow[r,<->,"D_3"]
  \arrow[d,<->,"\lvert a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\rangle \mapsto
                \begin{bsmallmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{bsmallmatrix}_{\scriptstyle B_{P_3}}"']
  &
  P_2
  \arrow[d,<->,"\lvert a+bx+cx^2\rangle \mapsto
                \begin{bsmallmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{bsmallmatrix}_{\scriptstyle B_{P_2}}"]
  \\
  \RR^4 \arrow[r,<->, "A"] & \RR^3
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


